# OpenGL ES 1.1 Vertex Buffer Object Not Working

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, vertex-buffer

I am developing an iPhone game using OpenGL ES 1.1 and need to use vertex buffer objects in order to render 500+ particles without the performance decreasing.

My game was able to draw successfully using the non-VBO method, but now that I've attempted to incorporate VBOs, nothing is drawing anymore.

Please help me to identify what I am doing wrong and provide a correct example.

I have a class called **TexturedQuad** which consists of the following:

```
// TexturedQuad.h

enum {
    ATTRIB_POSITION,
    ATTRIB_TEXTURE_COORD
 };

@interface TexturedQuad : NSObject {

    GLfloat *textureCoords; // 8 elements for 4 points (u and v)
    GLfloat *vertices;      // 8 elements for 4 points (x and y)
    GLubyte *indices;       // how many elements does this need?

    // vertex buffer array IDs generated using glGenBuffers(..)
    GLuint vertexBufferID;
    GLuint textureCoordBufferID;
    GLuint indexBufferID;

    // ...other ivars
}

// @synthesize in .m file for each property
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLfloat *textureCoords;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLfloat *vertices;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLubyte *indices;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLuint vertexBufferID;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLuint textureCoordBufferID;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) GLuint indexBufferID;

// vertex buffer object methods
- (void) createVertexBuffers;
- (void) createTextureCoordBuffers;
- (void) createIndexBuffer;
```

In **TexturedQuad.m**, the vertex buffers are created:

```
- (void) createVertexBuffers {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

- (void) createTextureCoordBuffers {
    glGenBuffers(1, &textureCoordBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textureCoords), textureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

- (void) createIndexBuffer {
    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLubyte) * 16, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

The above VBO creation methods are invoked by a custom **AtlasLibrary** class which initializes each TexturedQuad instance.

Firstly, the *vertices* are arranged in the following format:

```
// bottom left
quad.vertices[0] = xMin;
quad.vertices[1] = yMin;

// bottom right
quad.vertices[2] = xMax;
quad.vertices[3] = yMin;

// top left
quad.vertices[4] = xMin;
quad.vertices[5] = yMax;

// top right
quad.vertices[6] = xMax;
quad.vertices[7] = yMax;
```

Secondly, *texture* coordinates are arranged in the following format (flipped to account for OpenGL ES's tendency to mirror images):

```
// top left (of texture)
quad.textureCoords[0] = uMin;
quad.textureCoords[1] = vMax;

// top right
quad.textureCoords[2] = uMax;
quad.textureCoords[3] = vMax;

// bottom left
quad.textureCoords[4] = uMin;
quad.textureCoords[5] = vMin;

// bottom right
quad.textureCoords[6] = uMax;
quad.textureCoords[7] = vMin;
```

...next, the VBO-creation methods are called (in AtlasLibrary)

```
[quad createVertexBuffers];
[quad createTextureCoordBuffers];
[quad createIndexBuffer];
```

Now the meat and potatoes.  The **SceneObject** class.  SceneObjects are objects in the game that are renderable.  They reference a TexturedQuad instance and contain information about rotation, translation, and scale.

Here is the render method in SceneObject:

```
- (void) render {

    // binds texture in OpenGL ES if not already bound
    [[AtlasLibrary sharedAtlasLibrary] ensureContainingTextureAtlasIsBoundInOpenGLES:self.containingAtlasKey];

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z);

    glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);

    glScalef(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);

    // change alpha
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);

    // vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturedQuad.vertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GL_FLOAT), &texturedQuad.vertices[0]);


    // texture coords
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturedQuad.textureCoordBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GL_FLOAT), &texturedQuad.textureCoords[0]);

    // bind index buffer array
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturedQuad.indexBufferID);

    // draw
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(texturedQuad.indices) / sizeof(texturedQuad.indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturedQuad.indices);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

I have a strong feeling that either my indices array is structured incorrectly or that the glDrawElements(..) function is called incorrectly.

To answer this question, please:

- identify what I am doing incorrectly that would cause OpenGL ES to not draw my SceneObjects.
- provide the correct way to do what I am trying to do (according to my framework, please)
- provide any suggestions or links which may help (optional)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced in the differences between OpenGL and OpenGL ES, but I'm not seeing any calls to [glEnableVertexAttribArray()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml) in your code.

The function is suspiciously absent in the [OpenGL ES 1.1 docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/), but is in [2.0](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml), and is being used in [Apple's OpenGL ES VBO article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) (thanks [JSPerfUnkn0wn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649132/16434)).

Here are some other good (though, non-ES) tutorials on [Vertex Buffer Objects](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-2-vertices-and-shapes/), and [Index Buffer Objects](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-3-index-buffer-objects-and-primitive-types/).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, where are you loading the textures? You're setting texture coordinates but I see no glBindTexture. And I'm also assuming `alpha` is a valid value.

See [Apple OpenGL ES VBO article,](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) namely from Listing 9-1,  and this [OpenGL ES VBO tutorial](http://playcontrol.net/ewing/jibberjabber/opengl_vertex_buffer_object.html).

Comment: Yea, the textures are loading successfully.  The glBindTexture call is made in the method
    [[AtlasLibrary sharedAtlasLibrary] ensureContainingTextureAtlasIsBoundInOpenGLES:self.containingAtlasKey];

I know that part works because it was working before I tried using VBOs and haven't changed anything on that end since then.  So the texture loading and the binding is working.

Comment: Could've sworn I responded (or perhaps I did something silly like closed the window). IIRC my response was about the fact that `sizeof(vertices)` is 4, since vertices is a pointer. When calling `glVertexAttribPointer` instead of a pointer you give the offset into the buffer. I also provided a link that you could have compared your code with but I have absolutely no idea what it is now. It may have been [VBO - just examples](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples) judging by my history for 28 Dec. Hope it helps