# OpenGL ES - How to Batch Render 500+ particles w/ different alphas, rotations, and scales?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1, vertex-array

I am developing an iOS game that will need to render 500-800 particles at a time.  I have learned that it is a good idea to batch render many sprites in OpenGL ES instead of calling `glDrawArrays(..)` on every sprite in the game in order to be able to render more sprites w/out a drastic reduction in frame rate.

*My question is*: how do I **batch** render 500+ particles that all have different alphas, rotations, and scales, but share the same texture atlas?  The emphasis of this question is on the **different** *alphas*, *rotations*, and *scales* for each particle.

I realize this question is very similar to [How do I draw 1000+ particles (w/ unique rotation, scale, and alpha) in iPhone OpenGL ES particle system without slowing down the game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435123/how-do-i-draw-1000-particles-w-unique-rotation-scale-and-alpha-in-iphone-o), however, that question does not address batch rendering.  Before I take advantage of vertex buffer objects, I want to understand batch rendering in OpenGL ES w/ unique alphas, rotations, and scales (but with the same texture).  Therefore, while I plan on using VBOs eventually, I want to take this approach first.

Code examples would greatly be appreciated, and if you use an indices array as some examples do, please explain the structure and purpose of the indices array.

**EDIT** I am using OpenGL ES 1.1.

**EDIT** Below is a code example of how I render each particle in the scene.  Assume that they share the same texture and that texture is already bound in OpenGL ES 1.1 before this code executes.

```
- (void) render {

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z);

    glRotatef(rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);

    glScalef(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z);

    // change alpha
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);

    // glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedQuad.vertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedQuad.textureCoords);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

A code alternative to this method would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of opengl-es are you targeting?

Comment: I am using OpenGL ES 1.1 (noted in an edit).  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility would be to include those values in a vertex attrib array - I think this is the best option. If you're using OpenGL ES 1.1 instead of 2.0 you're screwed out of this method. Vertex attrib arrays allow you to store values at each vertex in this case you could store the alphas and rotations each in their own attrib array and pass them to the shader with `glVertexAttribArray`. The shader would then do the rotation transformation and color processing with the alpha.

The other option would be to do rotation transformation on the CPU, and then batch particles with a similar alpha values into several draw calls. This version would require a little bit more work and it would not be a single draw call but it would still help to optimize if the shader is not an option.

**NOTE: The question you linked to also recommends the array solution**

**EDIT:** Given your code here is an OpenGL ES 1.0, here's a solution using `glColorPointer`:

```
// allocate buffers to store an array of all particle data
verticesBuffer = ... 
texCoordBuffer = ...
colorBuffer = ...

for (particle in allParticles)
{
  // Create matrix from rotation
  rotMatrix = matrix(particle.rotation.x, particle.rotation.y, particle.rotation.z)
  // Transform particle by matrix
  verticesBuffer[i] = particle.vertices * rotMatrix

  // copy other data
  texCoordBuffer[i] = particle.texCoords;
  colorBuffer[i] = color(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, particle.alpha);
}

glVertexPointer(verticesBuffer, ...)
glTexCoordPointer(texCoodBuffer, ...)
glColorPointer(colorBuffer, ...)

glDrawArrays(particleCount * 4, ...);
```

A good optimization for this solution would be to share the buffers for each render so you don't have to reallocate them every frame.

Comment: Unfortunately since I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1, I will probably choose steer more towards the second option you mentioned.  +1 for that answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @TrueLifeCoder you should be able to reasonably get 4-10 draw calls depending on the amount of variation in alpha values you need. Are you storing particle rotations as matrices or something else?

Comment: @TrueLifeCoder I just realized with OpenGL ES 1.1 you could just use glColorPointer to pass color information for each vertex, rotation would still be done on the CPU but that could get it down to a single draw call

Comment: my rotations are stored as a struct type `XYZ` that has three CGFloats by x, y, and z coordinates.  Each particle has its own XYZ ivar. I have added an EDIT to my question to illustrate what I normally do.  Possibly you could provide a code alternative :)

Comment: @TrueLifeCoder I have edited my answer to show you an example of how to use glColorPointer